# Exchange limit and derivative: $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)=0$ implies $\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{d f(t)}{dt}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, absolute-continuity

Let $f(t)$ be absolutely continuous, uniformly bounded and such that $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)=0$. It should be true that
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{d}{dt} f(t)=0$$
but how can one prove it?

I'm trying to find the formal justification that allows to exchange the limit and the derivative.

Comment: I think your claim is false: consider $f(t) = \frac{1}{t} \sin (e^t)$ ($f(t) \to 0$ but $f'(t)$ is unbounded).

Comment: @ConnorHarris That function is not uniformly bounded.

Comment: @ConnorHarris I agree that that function is uniformly bounded and $f(t)\to 0$. But I'm not sure that it is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Ah, you're right, it's not absolutely continuous.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Why is it not uniformly bounded on, say $[1,\infty)$?

Comment: @Dr.MV Definitely is on that domain, I was assuming it was intended to be over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Cameron, yes true.  But inasmuch as $t\to \infty$, it doesn't matter much as to the behavior of $f$ except in a neighborhood of $\infty$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Very true!

Comment: $f(t)=\frac1t \sin(e^t)$ is uniformly continuous in $[1,\infty)$ but why is it so obvious that it is absolutely continuous in $[1,\infty)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is actually false. Construct a continuous integrable function
$g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\lbrack0,\infty)$ such that
$$
\liminf_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)=0<\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x).
$$
Note that this is done by taking $g$ to be a piecewise affine function which is zero
most of the time and at every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $g(n)=1$ and the area is the
one of a triangle of height one and basis $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$. Then define
$$
f(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}g(t)\,dt.
$$
The function $f$ is absolutely continuous since $g$ is integrable,
$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$ and $f$ is bounded by $\int_{\mathbb{R}%
}g(t)\,dt$ but $f^{\prime}(x)=-g(x)$ does not go to zero.

Comment: Thanks. $g(x)$ does not go to zero because the limit of $g(x)$ does not exist, am I correct? 
If the limit would exist then we may be in a position to apply barbalat’s lemma to conclude that the result is true
https://mathpost.asu.edu/~hliu/Things2Explain/Barbalat's%20lemma.pdf

Comment: correct, if the limit existed, it would have to be zero. For an integrable function you always need $\liminf_{x\to\infty}|g(x)|=0$